# Error "ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

¿Por qué me devuelve el error siguiente?

> ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.

Código:

```
public bool IngresarUsuario(Prueba objeto)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
    {
        try
        {                
            query= ("insert into Pruebas (Id,Nombre,Componente)values (@Id,@Nombre,@Componente)");
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            comando.Connection = cadena;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", objeto.Id);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", objeto.Nombre);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Componente", objeto.Componente);
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(comando.ExecuteNonQuery()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, lo primero viendo tu código es el bloque try/finally. Eso no es correcto desde el punto de vista de control de errores. Estás enmascarando (incluso ocultando) excepciones que se puedan producir en el método. Lo segundo es preguntar... que valor tiene la variable strConnection? Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abre la conexión antes de asignarla al SQLCommand.

```
public bool IngresarUsuario(Prueba objeto)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
    {
        try
        {  
            con.Open();     

            query= ("insert into Pruebas (Id,Nombre,Componente)values (@Id,@Nombre,@Componente)");
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            comando.Connection = cadena;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", objeto.Id);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", objeto.Nombre);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Componente", objeto.Componente);
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(comando.ExecuteNonQuery()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException sqlEx) 
        {
        // aquí hacer log o lo que sea
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        // aquí hacer log o lo que sea
        }
        finally 
        {
        // ¿Es necesario este bloque?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba quitando la línea siguiente:

```
comando.Connection = cadena; // cadena == null ??
```

No sé qué es `cadena` (no lo muestras), pero no parece correcto que lo estés usando aquí y probablemente esté a `null`. En cualquier caso, no necesitas hacer eso, ya que la conexión la estás pasando al objeto `comando` en su constructor:

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query,con); // ya le estás pasando "con" aquí
```

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario volver a llamar Connection ya que cuando haces esto...

```
     SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query,con);
```

Automáticamente indicas el query y la conexión que va a realizar. También te hace falta cerrar la conexión si no, cuando quieres abrir otra, te marcará error.

Comment: La conexión se cierra automáticamente al final del bloque `using`. No hay necesidad de hacerlo explícitamente. OP lo está haciendo bien.