# ¿Como solucionar el error no se ha inizializado la propiedad conexión?

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy tratando de modificar los datos de una base mediante unos `textbox` en `C#` pero cuando le doy clic al botón de modificar me lanza el error:

> ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad `Connection` no se ha *inicializado*.'

Este es el código del botón:

```
protected void btnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string ruta = ("Data Source=LAPTOP-3F5L5NNI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIADesarrollo;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlConnection oconeccion = new SqlConnection();
    oconeccion.ConnectionString = ruta;
    oconeccion.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Update cliente set idcliente = @idcliente, nombre = @nombre, direccion = @direccion, telefono = @telefono", oconeccion));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcliente", txtCliente.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtNombre.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    oconeccion.Close();
}
```

Comment: Revisa si lo expuesto en esta otra pregunta te sirve, el error parece ser el mismo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/error-executenonquery-la-propiedad-connection-no-se-ha-inicializado

Comment: Aprendiz intente las sugerencias que me daban en la otra pagina pero ninguna me funciono