# ¿Como resolver el error ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estoy tratando de modificar los datos de una base mediante unos textbox en c# pero cuando le doy clic al botón de modificar me lanza el error:

> ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.

este es el codigo del boton:

```
protected void btnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     string ruta = ("Data Source=LAPTOP-3F5L5NNI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIADesarrollo;Integrated Security=True");
     SqlConnection oconeccion = new SqlConnection();
     oconeccion.ConnectionString = ruta;
     oconeccion.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Update cliente set  nombre = @nombre, direccion = @direccion, telefono = @telefono where idcliente = @idcliente", oconeccion));
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcliente", txtCliente.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtNombre.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     oconeccion.Close();
 }
```

Comment: No dupliques preguntas : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264866/como-solucionar-el-error-no-se-ha-inizializado-la-propiedad-conexi%c3%b3n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilice bien los `using` para darle un orden a su código.

```
protected void btn_Modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ruta = "Data Source=LAPTOP-3F5L5NNI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIADesarrollo;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ruta))
    {
        string query = "Update cliente set  nombre = @nombre, direccion = @direccion, telefono = @telefono where idcliente = @idcliente"; 
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Prefiero Utilizar listas y no matrices para hacer el código mantenible.

```
List<SqlParameter> p = new List<SqlParameter>();
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@idcliente", txtCliente.Text));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@nombre", txtNombre.Text));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text));
```

Esto le permitirá introducir más elementos en sus parámetros sin tener que lidiar con los dolores de cabeza de la indexación explícita.

---

Aquí Esta todo junto...

```
protected void btn_Modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ruta = "Data Source=LAPTOP-3F5L5NNI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIADesarrollo;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ruta))
    {
        string query = "Update cliente set  nombre = @nombre, direccion = @direccion, telefono = @telefono where idcliente = @idcliente"; 
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
        {
            try
            {
                List<SqlParameter> p = new List<SqlParameter>();
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@idcliente", txtCliente.Text));
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@nombre", txtNombre.Text));
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text));
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text));

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Log de exepcciones
            }
        }
    }
}
```